# Rand() php случайно число из предложенных для ModX

Tags: php, modx, случайные-числа

Добрый день.
Имеется 3 числа, например (20, 125, 25)
Нужно запустить рандом, чтобы выпадало одно из этих чисел

У меня есть вызов getResources

```
[[!getResources? 
            &showHidden=`1` 
            &sortbyTV=`price`
            &sortdirTV=`ASC`
            &sortbyTVType=`integer`
            &tpl=`items` 
            &limit=`4` 
            &includeContent=`1` 
            &processTVs=`1` 
            &includeTVs=`image,tags,price` 
            &parents=`20,125,25`
        ]]
```

Необходимо вместо &parents выводить рандомно один из ресурсов

Comment: И в чем проблема получать случайное число от 0 до 2 и использовать как индекс в массиве с приведенными тремя числами?

Comment: проблема была не в том, чтобы получить число, а чтобы вывести именно в ModX это. В вызове getRes в строку нельзя нетривиальный код

Comment: Проблема была в том, что вы сформулировали вопрос про другое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем 2 варианта: простой, простой(но сложнее) -

**простой:**
Создаем сниппет randomItems:

```
$items = array(20,132,21,125,22,23,117,25,142,24);

return $items[rand(0,9)];
```

Недостатки:Клиенту (менеджеру) придется заходить в сниппет дабы изменить вызываемые ресурсы (коллекции, элементы которых отображаются на странице)

Вызов сниппета:

```
[[!getResources? 
            &showHidden=`1` 
            &sortbyTV=`price`
            &sortdirTV=`ASC`
            &sortbyTVType=`integer`
            &tpl=`items` 
            &limit=`4` 
            &includeContent=`1` 
            &processTVs=`1` 
            &includeTVs=`image,tags,price` 
            &parents=`[[randomItems]]`
]]
```

**сложнее**

```
$items = explode(",",$items);

for ($i=0; $i <count($items) ; $i++)
{
    $items[i] *= 1;
}

return $items[rand(0,count($items) - 1)];
```

Здесь мы принимаем массив из строк из чанка (или шаблона или еще чего).
Эксплодом делим на массив строк с разделителем ",".
Таким циклом преобразуем строки в числа и ретёрним рандомом.

Вызов сниппета:

```
[[!getResources? 
            &showHidden=`1` 
            &sortbyTV=`price`
            &sortdirTV=`ASC`
            &sortbyTVType=`integer`
            &tpl=`items` 
            &limit=`4` 
            &includeContent=`1` 
            &processTVs=`1` 
            &includeTVs=`image,tags,price` 
            &parents=`[[!randomItems? &items=`20,132,21,125,22,23,117,25,142,24`]]`
        ]]
```

*Не забываем восклицательный знак (!), чтобы элементы не кэшировались и отображались всегда разные элементы*

Answer (score 2):

```
$arrNumb = array(20,125,25);
$randNumb = $arrNumb[rand(0,2)];
```